# Are there any scriptures dedicated to nirakar ishvar?

Tags: nirguna, ishwara

Just like there are puranas and other books dedicated to specific gods
Are there any scriptures dedicated to nirgun nirakar bhraman
Not like in the vedantas which persuade you to know the bhraman but instead scriptures that are dedicated to bhakti towards a nirakar nirgun ishvar like the puranas are dedicated to the bhakti of the specific gods

Comment: Your question is like asking is there any mention of the sight of a piece of wood? By definition there cannot be any scriptures for something which is formless, nameless, dimension-less, thoughtless, qualityless etc. How will you have bhakti towards something you cannot even name or see or hear or touch or think about?

Answer (score 0):

Shiva Linga is a symbol of formless nirguna Brahman.

Shiva Purana 1.9.:

> 30. I have two forms: the manifest and the unmanifest. No one else has these two forms. Hence all else are non-Īśvaras.
>
> 31-32. Dear sons, first in the form of the column (linga) and afterwards in this embodied form I have expounded to you my formless Brahma-hood, and embodied Īśa-hood. These two are present only in me and not in anyone else. Hence no one else, not even you too can claim Īśatva (Īśa-hood).

Linga Purana talks about the glory and greatness of Linga.

Linga Purana 1.1.:

> On seeing the truly trustworthy and scholarly Sūta Romaharṣaṇa there arose in them the desire to hear the Purāṇa. They, thereafter, asked him about the meritorious Purāṇa that contained the glory and greatness of the Lingas.

It's the best of all the Puranas.

Narada Purana 102.4.:

> Lord Brahmā said to Nārada.: 4. It (Linga Purāna) indicates the greatness of Hara. It is greater than all the other Puranas. It is the essence of the three worlds.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Comment: What is point of "nirakar" Parambrham, if idol ,image or any symbol can exist???       Explain

Comment: Linga is not an idol but yes a symbol like pranava. A symbol is always necessary. The reason is as follows.: ***43. The phallic symbol and the symbolised Śiva are non-different. Hence this phallic emblem is identical with me. It brings devotees quite near to me. It is worthy of worship therefore...46. The installation of the phallic emblem is primary and that of embodied idol is secondary. A temple with the embodied idol of Śiva is unfructuous if it has no phallic image.*** So, linga is a symbol beyond idol worship. It's the worship of nirakar brahman while idol are of sakar brahman.

Comment: Please give chapter where such verses are written. I  think I must check hindi translation .

Comment: Shiva Puran 1.9.43 and 46.